# Is what I am doing preventing Deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I have 12 resources (r_1, r_2, ..., r_12), and 12 corresponding locks (l_1, l_2, ..., l_12) that my threads try to access. Each thread needs a specific sequence of resources to operate on. For example, thread 1 needs r_1, r_3, and r_5. Thread 2 needs r_1, r_7, r_8, r_10.

Now what I've basically done is ordered the resources from 1 to 12, make each thread lock its required resources in this order (ascending order), then when the thread is done, I unlock them in the reverse order (descending order) to maintain an order.

So my question is, am I **preventing** a deadlock in this case? Or can there happen a deadlock?

Comment: Also English is not my first language so apologies if something is not clear.

Comment: I think that will work. I'm not certain it is optimal

Comment: @AspiringMat Your question is perfectly clear.. It's almost like a math problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes, this system is totally immune to deadlock. At any point in time, the thread holding the highest-numbered lock *must* be able to make progress, since it cannot be waiting to acquire any locks held by other processes. More formally, your conditions ensure a total ordering on lock acquisition by all processes, which in turn ensures that circular wait can never occur. Circular wait is a necessary precondition for deadlock.

**Detail**:  In order for deadlock to take place, all four of the following conditions must apply (see relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)):

1. **Mutual exclusion** - i.e. concurrent processes are accessing *unsharable* resources. Locks are unsharable by definition (they are also called *mutexes* for this reason).
2. **Hold and wait** - at least one process is attempting to access multiple resources, and it does so by holding some of them and then waiting for the others. This condition *probably* applies in your case, depending on the exact semantics of your program.
3. **No preemption** - it is not possible for processes to have their resources taken from them by other processes. Once again, this is a property of the locks we're using.
4. **Circular wait** - there is a cycle of processes, each waiting on a resource held by the next. This condition **doesn't** apply here. Consider a thread A, waiting on accessing a lock L_i. That lock must be held by a thread B which has already obtained all the locks it requires from indices 1 to i. As a result, B cannot be waiting on A. Similarly, any thread that B is waiting on in order to acquire its next lock L_j (where j > i by the order in which locks are acquired) cannot be waiting on any locks with indices 1 to j. By induction, there can be no cycles of dependency in this system.

In concurrent programming, it is typical for the first three cases to be set by the context in which you are developing (which concurrency primitives are being used etc.), whereas the last can occasionally™ be avoided by cleverness.